# How display big text inside of div properly

Tags: html, css

Sorry but I think I'm forgeting css right now and I could not find the clue for this my problem is there any way to diplay accordingly and reponsieve way inside of `leftSide` div?

**HTML**

```
<div class='mainPage'>
        <div class="leftSide">
            <h2 class='md-display-4'>EventUpside</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="rightSide"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mainPage {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background: red;
    }

    .leftSide {
        width: 35%;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    }

    .rightSide {
        width: 65%;
        height: 40px;
        float: right;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    }
.md-display-4 {
  font-size: 11.2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: -.01em;
  line-height: 11.2rem;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Shaxrillo/35so3w07/)

Comment: @berblexer I think it is not problem with font

Comment: I think it's not clear what you want - I would have thought you were asking how to resize the font to be large but fit inside the div even when resizing. I would think this means reducing the size of the font as the div reduces in width. If that's right then the issue is the root em sizing (rem) and berblexer's suggestion is worth looking at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is what you want, but try setting

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

to your .md-display-4 CSS properties

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/35so3w07/3/

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the width value for `.leftSide`, the div will be as big as its content. Or do you want to fit the font inside the div with defined width.
Something like

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

inside the .md-display-4 could help. Or should the size of the font change?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

As the screen scales, so will the text.

Answer (score 0):

Add `word-wrap: break-word;` to `.leftSide`.

This will make the contained text to stay in the div by breaking the text when it reaches the edge of the div. It also works if you change the div's width - the wider the div the more text you can display in one line.